# I am trying to make a Parser with ocamlyacc for a Language, but what type should I put?

Tags: parsing, ocaml, ocamllex, ocamlyacc, menhir

I have the following code also have more after like expr: int {} | BOOL {} etc but i dont know what is the type that i should write in type of this parser, i have a calculator example that works with int and the type is int , but in my program i have float char string etc .. Thanks

```
  %{
dont know what to write here

 %}

 %token <int> INT
 %token <float> FLOAT
 %token <char> CHAR
 %token <bool> BOOL
 %token <string> IDENT
 %token PLUS Div Bigger Smaller MINUS TIMES 
%token TYPE
%token DEF DD
%token Equals Atribuicao SoE BoE And Or
%token IF ELSE BEGIN END WHILE RETURN PV SEQ TO BY OF 
%token RP LP LB RB  
%token EOL
%left Bigger Smaller SoE BoE Equals Atribuicao Or And
%left PLUS MINUS       
%left TIMES Div        
%nonassoc UMINUS OF  

%start main          

%type <> main /* what should be in here ? */


main:
| expr EOL                { $1 }
expr:           
  INT                   {  }    
| BOOL                  {  }  
| FLOAT                 {  }
| CHAR                  {  } 
| expr OF expr              {   }
| BEGIN expr END            {   }
| RETURN expr PV            { $2 }
| LP expr RP                { $2 }
| LB expr RB                { $2 } 
| expr PLUS expr            {  }
| expr MINUS expr           {  }
| expr TIMES expr               {  }
%%

let main() = begin
 Printf.printf "Hello yo\n" ;

end;;
```

Answer (score 2):

Judging from your grammar, the return type should be something like `expression`, because it is expressions that you do parse. How you define that type depends on the semantics you want to implement. I guess that you will need a variant type that can at least hold atoms of type `int`, `bool`, `float` and `char`. So you can start with

```
type expression =
| Int of int
| Bool of bool
| Float of float
| Char of char
```

and see where it takes you.